# Determination of limit of a nonconstant function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $f(x) = f(x + 2)$ for every real number $x$

Tags: limits

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a nonconstant function satisfying $f(x + 2) = f(x)$ for every real $x$. Then $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$

(A) does not exist.

(B) exists and equals $+\infty$ or $−\infty$.

(C) exists and is finite.

(D) may or may not exist depending on $f$.

Comment: Is it okay to say that "f(x) = f(x + 2) " is same as y=x + 2 ?

Comment: No. The equation $f(x) = f(x+2)$ says that $f$ is periodic with period 2.

Comment: Since it is non-contant there are $x,y\in[0,2)$ with $x\neq y$ and $f(x)\neq f(y)$. Look at $f(x+2k)$ and $f(y+2k)$ for $k=1,2,3,...$. This is similar to what you do to prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin(x)$ doesn't exist.

Comment: @JoshuaRuiter so A must be the answer?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is (A). To prove this, let $x,y$ be reals such that $f(x)\neq f(y)$. Then, set $x_n=x+2n$ and $y_n=y+2n$. What happens when we take the limit of $f$ applied to each subsequence?